# Multiple Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make dropdown menu close by clicking on another one?
When I click on dropdown menu it opens, then I click on another one and the menu, which was opened doesnt close. Help me please

**HTML:**

```
`<div class="dropdown">
   <button onclick="myFunction(this)"; class="buy-room-button hero-section-button">
      Buy room <img src="icons/arrow-down-black.png" alt="">
   </button>
   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
   </div> 
</div>`
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction(a) {
                a.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0].classList.toggle("show");
            }

            onclick = function(event) {
                if(!event.target.matches('.hero-section-button')) {
                    let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
                    let i;
                    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                        let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where is other `.dropdown` menu will be?

Comment: The three dropdown menus are aligned in a horizontal row. 
Just two more <div class="dropdown">...</div> on the right to the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select siblings of clicked `btn`'s parent and remove `.show` from `.dropdown-content` in them.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".buy-room-button").forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement;
    const siblings = [...parent.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".dropdown")].filter((d) => d != parent);
    parent.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
    siblings.forEach((s) => s.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.remove("show"));
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content.show {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="buy-room-button hero-section-button">
                Buy room <img src="icons/arrow-down-black.png" alt="">
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="buy-room-button hero-section-button">
                Buy room <img src="icons/arrow-down-black.png" alt="">
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```